# Phonegap application in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

I am a beginner in developing application in phone gap
I installed phone gap and cordova in my Mac from terminal
created the project following the documentation on the website

I tried to see different tutorials online on how to create application in iOS
but they are all using different project structure than the latest one
so I get confuse in which `index.html` file I should be modifying

I have included the project structure of my project
I also don't know why that file `merges` is in red color
is it installed and created perfectly my project 
or I did some mistake creating the project.

Also I simply tried to display a `button` in iOS simulator
having problem displaying button and adding a `click` event on the button

Let me know of latest tutorials or tell me if I did any mistake installing phone gap

In the last screenshot of my simulator

thank you
[image: index.html file]
[image: project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling the project from command line then you need to make changes in index.html file which is in directory of **YourAppDirectory -> www -> index.html** not the **YourAppDirectory -> platforms -> ios -> www -> index.html** because compilation make changes according to the `index.html` which is in **YourAppDirectory -> www**. After compilation, you will see changes in your platform based files.

Comment: thats what i thought but when i make any changes in **directory->www->index.html** compile it from Xcode and run it. it doesn't make any changes. So are you saying that i should make changes in **directory->www->index.html** and compile it from command line and run it in simulator?

Comment: no its not working.. no matter what changes i make in **directory->www->index.html** and compile using **cordova build iOS** it and run it in simulator it displays the content from the page **directory->platform->iOS->www->index.html**

Comment: after compilation is there any error in terminal? After successful compilation, changes made in directory->www->index.html should reflect in directory->platform->iOS->www->index.html. Clean your xcode project after compilation and see changes.

Comment: yes you are right. whatever changes i make in general **index.html** is reflected after successful build but now the problem is something else with iPhone simulator. When i run the project simulator doesn't run at all..

Comment: Ok. Try restarting simulator and remove already installed app.